# Computing the volume of a regular tetrahedron with edge length

Tags: javascript

Im trying to figure out how to write a JavaScript program that computes and outputs the volume of a regular tetrahedron. This is how far I got but it seems to get a error and not compute the right numbers after.

The equation for the triangle is

v = a3

6 √ 2

Sorry about the code i dont know how to post things on here very effectively. So this is my variables

```
var a =  parseFloat(document.getElementById('length').value);
var b = (a * a * a) / 6 * Math.sqrt(2)
```

Comment: Give us expected inputs and outputs, as well as the formula for calculating the volume of a tetrahedron.  And give us the error.  We aren't psychic, generally.

Comment: You should check parentheses in your second variable assignment. Currently you are not dividing by 6*Math.sqrt(2). Or are there any other errors despite an invalid volume?

Comment: When you get an error, and unexpected output, it is expected that you provide said error and unexpected output in addition to the expected output directly within the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. You are missing some parenthesis around `6 * Math.sqrt(2)`

Your code is doing `(a*a*a) / 6` and *then* multiplying that result by the square root of 2.

You can read up on [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

```js
var a = 4;
var b = (a * a * a) / (6 * Math.sqrt(2))
console.log(b);
```

You can also use [Math.pow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow)

```js
var a = 4;
var b = Math.pow(a,3) / (6 * Math.sqrt(2))
console.log(b);
```